# Sinatra DataMapper one-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby, sinatra, ruby-datamapper

Im new to Sinatra, and I have a problem with DataMapper one-to-many relationship

**db.rb**

```
env = ENV["RACK_ENV"]
url = Dir.pwd + "/db/#{env}"
DataMapper.setup :default, "sqlite://#{url}.sqlite3"

class Order
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :client, String

  has n, :order_items
end

class OrderItem
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :dish_id, Integer

  belongs_to :order
end

DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```

**dishes.rb**

```
DISHES = [
  { id: 1, name: "Mac and Cheese", category: "Pasta", price: 10 },
  { id: 2, name: "Steak", category: "Meat", price: 9 },
  { id: 3, name: "Fish and Chips", category: "Fish", price: 12 },
  { id: 4, name: "Tiramisu", category: "Dessert", price: 5 }
]
```

**app.rb**

```
get do
  @orders = Order.all
  @dishes = DISHES

  haml %s(orders/index)
end
```

**index.haml**

```
%table.row
  -@orders.each do |order|
    %tr
      %td=order.client
      %td
        %ul
          -order.order_items.each do |item|
            %li
              -@dishes.select { |dish| dish[:id] == item.dish_id }.first[:name]
```

this line:

```
-@dishes.select { |dish| dish[:id] == item.dish_id }.first[:name]
```

Not showing any dishes that client has already picked, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I was stupid, this line:

```
-@dishes.select { |dish| dish[:id] == item.dish_id }.first[:name]
```

Should be:

```
=@dishes.select { |dish| dish[:id] == item.dish_id }.first[:name]
```

so it will print out the results, I found the solution after I change it to erb format for a while.